# calculating timestamp in iOS for core data project

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, datetime, timestamp

I am using core data in my project. Database is sqlite and there is column for storing "birthdate" having datatype "timestamp".

Now, I want to insert some records in it and I am having dates in human readable format like "1809-06-17".

How to convert this date to timestamp so that, I get this date when fetched from database.

I tried some conversions using python script, but I got different results.

Is there any easy way to do this? Please help me.

Comment: To generate a date of that format to store in the future you will need to take a look at `NSDateFormatter`. This will allow you to create any arbitrary date format which you can then use to covert any date to and from.
I am assuming you are looking to get timestamps later and then add them to your CoreData objects in the format you mentioned above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could store the date as TEXT and dont have to worry about converting to and from timestamp.

To convert timestamp to NSDate use:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeStamp];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

String to NSDate to timestamp:

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithString:stringWithDate];
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
```

SQLite doesnt have a datatype for Date, it just stores it in a INT (Unix Time), REAL(Julian day numbers) or TEXT(ISO8601 strings) depending on what you choose.

So you could just store the date in the format you already have ("1809-06-17") as a TEXT column or you store as a timestamp in an INT column using the methods above to convert both ways.

SQLite Date and Time functions: [SQLite date and time](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)
SQLite DATATYPES: [SQLite datatypes doc](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
SQLite Oficial Site and Documentation: [SQLite Home](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Hope you can solve your problem

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I need to convert "1809-06-17" to timestamp and store it into database. I have tried one solution which gives correct values for year around 1950.                                                                    Solution:                                                      import time
from datetime import datetime

ref = time.mktime(datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).timetuple())
now = time.time() - ref

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution I needed.

```
    
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];    
NSDate * past = [df dateFromString:@"1971-04-06"];
NSTimeInterval oldTime = [past timeIntervalSinceDate:[df dateFromString:@"2001-01-01"]];
NSString * unixTime = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%0.0f", oldTime];
NSLog(@"unixTime = %@",unixTime);
```